# Make It Easy for Users to Find Paused Flow Interviews for a Record - Test Class

Tags: unit-test, visual-workflow, class, flow-interviews

Has anyone successfully created a test class for this?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_pause_cmp_record.htm&type=5

Comment: Jay, see this post:

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319507/test-class-apex-controller-for-lwc-bundle-that-displays-flow-pause-component/320678#320678