# Test class - Apex Controller for LWC bundle that displays Flow pause component

Tags: unit-test, controller

The out of the box Lightning Component that shows Flow Interview Pauses can only be added to a Lightning Page type of HOME. Users need it on the record page.

I found a solution in the Salesforce help pages:  [Make It Easy for Users to Find Paused Flow Interviews for a Record](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_pause_cmp_record.htm&type=5). This page has an Aura component, Apex Controller, JS Controller and JS helper. With a little style tweaking I was able to get it to exactly what the customer needed.

In the sandbox that is… No test class provided. Need a test class for the Apex Controller (code copied below). Being a novice developer, not sure how to write a test class for a Flow Pause situation.

Has anyone already found/used this solution and written a test class you’d be willing to share? If so, many thanks in advance. And if not, any advice as to how to write it?

Apex Controller ([other code here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_pause_cmp_record.htm&type=5))

```
public class interviewsByRecordController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<FlowRecordRelation> getInterviews(Id recordId) {
        return [ SELECT 
                    ParentId, Parent.InterviewLabel, Parent.PauseLabel, 
                    Parent.CurrentElement, Parent.CreatedDate, Parent.Owner.Name 
                FROM FlowRecordRelation 
                WHERE RelatedRecordId = :recordId ];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static FlowInterview deleteInterview(Id interviewId) {
        FlowInterview interview = [Select Id from FlowInterview Where Id = :interviewId];
        delete interview;
        return interview;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a colleague help me out with this. The way the controller was written made it difficult to test, so tweaked it slightly and got the test class coverage at 100%. Regression tested, deployed - all good.

**Updated Controller:**

```
    public class interviewsByRecordController {

        @AuraEnabled
        public static List<FlowRecordRelation> getInterviews(Id recordId) {
            return [SELECT ParentId, Parent.InterviewLabel, Parent.PauseLabel,         Parent.CurrentElement, Parent.CreatedDate, Parent.Owner.Name
                    FROM FlowRecordRelation
                    WHERE RelatedRecordId = :recordId];
        }

        @AuraEnabled
        public static FlowInterview deleteInterview(Id interviewId) {
            FlowInterview interview;
            delete [SELECT Id FROM FlowInterview WHERE Id = :interviewId];
            return interview;
        }
    }
```

**Test class:**

```
    @IsTest
    private class interviewsByRecordController_Test {
        @IsTest
        static void testBehavior() {
            Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
            insert acct;
            Test.startTest();
            System.assertNotEquals(null, interviewsByRecordController.getInterviews(acct.Id));
            System.assertEquals(null, interviewsByRecordController.deleteInterview(acct.Id));
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
```